# Building Android apps with Maven - SDK Path

Tags: java, android, maven, plugins, build

I've been struggling the past week or so with building various example Android applications using Maven.  I've been on several pages on Google trying to find out what is going wrong but no luck.

I am getting the following exception

```
  Error when generating sources.
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: No Android SDK path could be found. You may configure it in the plugin configuration section in the pom file using <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> or <properties><android.sdk.path>...</android.sdk.path></properties> or on command-line using -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or by setting environment variable ANDROID_HOME
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo.getAndroidHomeOrThrow(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:864)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo.getAndroidSdk(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:833)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:329)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Running this command, it seems like I have the ANROID_HOME variable set

```
megaz@Wolverine:/$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/megaz/Documents/android-sdk-linux_x86/


megaz@Wolverine:/$ ls /home/megaz/Documents/android-sdk-linux_x86/
add-ons  docs  extras  platforms  platform-tools  samples  SDK Readme.txt  sources  system-images  temp  tools
```

Comment: did you download the Android SDK?

Comment: Did you tried to use properties?  or configuration embedded into  pom?  what about enabling debugging (-X)

Comment: Yes, I have the SDK and -X produces the same Maven exception.  I've also tried the configuration embedded into pom approach and still no luck.

Comment: And do you have the android maven plugin?

Comment: Yes, just to add, i can't run maven 3 unless i use sudo.  Could this be an issue?

Comment: can you set your path like this? PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANT_HOME/bin:$M2:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: AFAIR actual version of maven android plugin requires maven 3 ( got my ass bitten of on this issue once)

Comment: _i can't run maven 3 unless i use sudo. Could this be an issue?_ Perhaps, make sure your profile have proper permission to access SDK install directory and Maven related directory.